# TypeError: "t.endPicker.do is not a function"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, datepicker

TypeError: "t.endPicker.do is not a function"
    mounted frontend.js?ver=2.4.1:3107
    VueJS 2

### vue.min.js:6:11752

Hi
i tried to change a Datepicker for Wordpress Theme and
this Shows Up!
but on another theme its just works fine!
i dont know what am i doing wrong
any one can help?

---

Here is the Frontend.js Code:

> ```
>             this.$nextTick(function() {
>                 var e = t.enableTimepicker;
>                 t.startPicker = new MyListing.Datepicker(t.$refs.start, {
>                     timepicker: e
>                 }), t.endPicker = new MyListing.Datepicker(t.$refs.end, {
>                     timepicker: e
>                 }), t.endPicker.do(function(e) {
>                     return e.drp.minDate = moment(t.startDate)
>                 }), new MyListing.CustomSelect(t.$refs.select), t.$root.$on("reset-filters:" + t.listingType, function() {
>                     t.locked = !0, t.selected = t.presets.length ? t.presets[0].key : "@custom", t.startPicker.setValue(moment("")),
> ```
>
> t.endPicker.setValue(moment("")), t.locked = !1
>                       })
>                   })

here is the Vue.js Code:

> ......if(!a&&!o(t)||Object.isFrozen(t)||t instanceof
>   pe)return;if(t.**ob**){var
>   s=t.**ob**.dep.id;if(n.has(s))return;n.add(s)}if(a)for(r=t.length;r--;)e(t[r],n);else
>   for(i=Object.keys(t),r=i.length;r--;)e(t[i[r]],n)}(e,Qe),Qe.clear()}var
>   tt=g(function(e){var
>   t="&"===e.charAt(0),n="~"===(e=t?e.slice(1):e).charAt(0),r="!"===(e=n?e.slice(1):e).charAt(0);return{name:e=r?e.slice(1):e,once:n,capture:r,passive:t}});function
>   nt(e,t){function n(){var
>   e=arguments,r=n.fns;if(!Array.isArray(r))return
>   He(r,null,arguments,t,"v-on handler");for(var
>   i=r.slice(),o=0;o0&&(st((u=e(u,(a||"")+"_"+c))[0])&&st(f)&&.....

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Without knowing what `t` and `enableTimePicker` are, chances are nobody will be able to help you. You have to show the source code producing this error which is, most likely, in one of your Vue components, using some form of time-picker. Chances are `t` is actually `jQuery` in your minified code and you're instantiating some component that assumes `enableTimePicker` exists as a `$.fn` (plugin), before registering the plugin. But that's just a wild guess, it could be something totally different and there's no way to tell from what you posted. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: There are various ways to determine where the error originates from but, basically, you need someone decent at debugging JavaScript. In current form, your question is *off-topic* here, as you're only reporting an error and asking people to fix it for you, without showing anything related to your development and/or research efforts. Although it's sometimes not obvious, that's outside of [SO]s scope. SO is a community of developers helping each other learn and grow, it's not a free debugging/development services provider. Please read [ask].